# How to check if and which mouse button is pressed in Swing

Tags: java, swing, mouse, mouse-listeners

How can I check if currently any mouse button is pressed and if so, which one it is?

The thing is that I need to use this kind of information in `MouseListener.mouseEntered()`. I checked `MouseEvent` but I could not find the method which would help me.

The `getButton()` method seems to only return value if there has been change in buttons' state.

Is there a way to find this out without manually keeping track of this somehow vie `MouseListener.mousePressed()/mouseReleased()` methods.

Comment: How is it possible to get the mouse button when its a mouse enter event. If button is clicked then it will become a mouse drag event. Try `addMouseMotionListener` instead of `addMouseListener`.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo `getModifiers` will tell you what key's are active when the mouse event occurred (it's a method of `InputEvent`), `getButton`will tell you which buttons were active when the event was raised, but `SwingUtilities.isXxxButton` is a safe, cross platform mechanism, which is normally recommended, to determine which buttons were actually pressed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I check if currently any mouse button is pressed and if so, which one it is?

Presumably you want to invoke specific code depending on the button pressed so you can do something like:

```
if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(...))
   // do something
```

Answer (score 3):

You could start by looking at [How to write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and the [JavaDocs for MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) in particular, the [getButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getButton%28%29) method.

However, there are cross platform considerations that need to taken into consideration, which are overed by [SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isLeftMouseButton%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) and equivalent methods...

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem

```
    long eventMask = AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK + AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK;

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.paramString()+"-"+e.getSource());
        }
    }, eventMask);
```

This is a [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/).

Get the source and button from `AWTEvent` and do whatever you want to perform.

Comment: Here is the one of the value of `paramString` **MOUSE_ENTERED,(470,268),absolute(470,268),button=0,clickCount=0**. Now we can get mouse event type, mouse position, button as well as click count.

Comment: Don't tell me, tell the OP ;)

Comment: Its obvious for OP, if he/she try it. I have mentioned it already in my post. :)